# what does <xsl:value-of select = "."/> mean in an xsl file

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT file and in this file there are statements `<xsl:value-of select = "."/>`

Can anyone tell me what does `select = "."` mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I remember correctly `select="xpath/selector"` hence `<xsl:value-of />` will yield the value at the described xPath.

As described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) `.` selects the current node much the same way as `.` selects the current folder in a file system path.

Comment: @user2220658 - Here's another resource to check out: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

Answer (score 1):

"." is the current node - it's value depends on which template or 
xslt instruction it is processing.